# Java : version verification error in MAC OSX terminal

Tags: java, macos, terminal

i'm new to mac. and i installed the netbeans IDE . so i just went to verify it in the terminal. then i'm getting an error while finding out the version ?[this is the screenshot of the terminal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqOsG.png)

Comment: VTC typo. `java -version` **not** `java -version.`

Comment: thank you so much. can you help me how to compile and run java using my mac terminal. the version is " java version "1.8.0_141"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_141-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.141-b15, mixed mode)"

Answer (score 0):

You should write to terminal like this

```
java -version
```

Comment: check this for compile and run java in terminal
http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/mac-cmd.html

Comment: cant we write the c or c++ or java programs in terminal itself and compile and run? since i have xcode and netbeans ide i can compile and run my programs there itself right?? . so whats the use of compiling and running in the terminal when we can do it in xcode etc?

Comment: can u please acknowledge me or teach me the advantages please @stoler

Comment: I think there is no difference between what you say or do. I'm not familiar with the subject at advanced level.

Answer (score 0):

From the NetBeans IDE, you can select the 'Tools' menu drop-down at the top of the screen.  This has an option, 'Java Platforms'.  Clicking on this will bring up a window that shows details of the Java platforms you have configured.  For each platform the Platform Folder is displayed, which will include the version information in the directory name.